# Multiple Comparison Correct Group of Confidence Intervals

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons

I have a number of data points (~10,000) compared against different confidence intervals to determine whether or not they are significantly elevated or not.

Now I would like to correct for multiple comparison testing, but the only way I know how to do this is by using the p-values from each comparison, which I don't have because they were compared to a confidence interval.

How can I correct for multiple comparison?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to correct for $m$ multiple comparisons when it comes to hypothesis tests is the Bonferroni correction: by rejecting each null hypothesis $H_i:i\in\{1,2,...,m\}$ at a Type 1 error rate $\alpha/m$, the familywise error rate (FWER) is controlled at $\leq \alpha$.

The Bonferroni correction is derived from the Boole-Frechet inequalities, which relates the probabilities of multiple events to the probability of their intersection and the probability of their union. Given $m$ events $E_i:i\in\{1,2,...,m\}$,

$1-m+\sum^m_{i=1}P(E_i) \leq P(\bigcap^m_{i=1}E_i) \leq \min(P(E_i):i\in\{1,2,...,m\}) \leq \max(P(E_i):i\in\{1,2,...,m\}) \leq P(\bigcup^m_{i=1}E_i) \leq \sum^m_{i=1}P(E_i)$

Say the event $E_i$ is a Type 1 error for the $i$th test, then if all $P(E_i)=\alpha/m$, the FWER $P(\bigcup^m_{i=1}E_i) \leq m\alpha/m=\alpha$. It's that simple.

With multiple confidence intervals, the event $E_i$ is each interval. You're interested in controlling the probability that all confidence intervals contain their estimated parameter, say $\geq 1-\alpha$. In this case we're looking at the intersection probability, and assuming the individual confidences $P(E_i)$ are all equal: $1-\alpha = 1-m+mP(E_i) \leq P(\bigcap^m_{i=1}E_i)$. It follows that $P(E_i)=1-\alpha/m$.